# Questions deleted by moderator should be grayed out for undelete

Tags: bug, 10k-tools

Questions deleted by moderator should be grayed out for undelete as no-one (other than a mod I guess) can cast an undelete vote.

This would bring it in line with the grayed out un/delete answer votes based on rep.

[image]

Where the second link is [Install another OS](https://superuser.com/questions/389618/install-another-os).

Comment: Have you tried to cast undelete on injured question?

Comment: @random, not sure what you mean by injured, but I tried to cast an undelete vote when I arrived at the page (I was not aware of this restriction until now)

Comment: Does it display a message saying "This question was deleted by a moderator, and cannot be undeleted?"  If it does  that, then it's working the way it is supposed to.  By offering the link and then providing an error message, you are teaching people how the system works, instead of confusing them by dimming the link for mysterious reasons.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Right now in tools, it looks normal, and only when you go to the the question and try to vote does it tell you that. You only need to learn once.

Comment: OK, well deletion by a mod is pretty obvious.  What do you mean by "in tools?"

Comment: @RobertHarvey, see edit.

Answer (score 1):

[@RobertHarvey commented](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137335/questions-deleted-by-moderator-should-be-grayed-out-for-undelete#comment384579_137335):

> Does it display a message saying *"This question was deleted by a moderator, and cannot be undeleted?"* If it does that, then it's working the way it is supposed to. By offering the link and then providing an error message, you are teaching people how the system works, instead of confusing them by dimming the link for mysterious reasons.

To the contrary, I'm always, (well every now and then, but enough to notice and search for a bug on *SE.Meta*), clicking these things because:

- It's clickable, and the deletion seems needless.
- To avoid a needless click the user must to learn and remember *which users are moderators*.  There are so many SE communities, whose ranks may change, it's impossible for users without photographic memories to remember who's moderating what.

  Good moderation is transparent, usually [users shouldn't need to know who the moderators are](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_Make_Me_Think), anymore than vacationers travelling cross country need to know the names of the mayors in every town they find lodging.

To forbid entry to some building local governments don't leave its front door unlocked, so that people blithely open that door, which is then obstructed by a 3-foot [door chain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Door_chain), hanging from which is a sign, *"CLOSED: by order of Mayor."*  Instead The doors *are* locked, and [barricade tape](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barricade_tape) is placed *before* the door, (or entrance), possibly with explanatory signage.

Suggested improvement:

- Gray out the *undelete* link.
- Next to the grayed out link in parentheses write:  *closed by moderator*, or if that's too busy, put a clickable *M* or [*"No Symbol"*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No_symbol) which when clicked offers more information.